# SharePoint 2010 search results returning invalid results

Tags: search-results

We are using OOTB search feature in our team sites.
We deleted one word in a word document and saved it to document library. After 3 days, when we search with the deleted word, the results returning the document, even though that document does not have that deleted word inside it.
Full crawl and incremental crawl ares scheduled and running on a daily basis without issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the index is corrupted. You may try resetting the index.